# update homepage / landing page for google search

Tags: facebook, magento, seo, meta-tags, google-search

We're in the process of launching our Magento [website](http://akaknits.com/).  Everything is live now & we've taken down our 'coming soon' page.  The problem is our 'coming soon' page is what is showing up in google search & when we add a link to our site on facebook.

Is there a method to change this or do we have to wait for Google to update?

We've submitted a sitemap to google.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a useful article which explains how you can request that Google removes old cached pages for your site from it's search results.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663660?hl=en#

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just wait for 2 or 3 days and GG is going to update the result with your new website.

Answer (score 0):

If that "coming soon" page was not your site landing page, you can add that URL to **robots.txt** file. By the way, just wait for a day or two! The sitemap will do the job and soon update their database. Don't forget to try Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: the 'coming soon' page was our index.html file but we've removed it & our site is now using index.php, what is the robots.txt file?

Comment: I've tried Google Webmaster tools & went to Crawl < Fetch as Google & submited our URL to index.  I hope this helps?

Comment: robots.txt file is used to blacklist pages from Google crawler. But it was your index file so leave that for now. Just keep patience and good luck for your site!